# Python states Key Error when creating a new variable in a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, local-variables, keyerror

I am in the process of cleaning many variables(columns in a data frame) to perform text analysis on said variables.

I have a data frame called econ_data.

Here I create a 'list' of all the variables that need to be transformed, for example transforming all text to lower case and removing stop words.

```
open_responses = ['choice_open_1_f', 'choice_open_1_m', 'choice_open_2_f ', 'choice_open_2_m']
```

Then I want to create a for loop that cleans up these variables so that I can perform text analysis.

```
for z in open_responses:
    econ_data[z] = econ_data[z].astype(str).str.replace('/',' ')
    econ_data[z] = econ_data[z].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.lower() for x in x.split()))
    locals()[econ_data[f"{z}_stop"]] = econ_data[f"{z}"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in x.split() if x not in stop_words))
```

The first 2 lines in the for loop work, however, when I try to add a new variable to the data frame when stop words have been removed from the entry, I receive a Key Error message ("KeyError: 'choice_open_1_f_stop'").

[image: Error message]

Please can someone explain how I can solve this issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: The error instructs that you do not have those columns in the dataframe. Without a mocked dataframe we cannot assert this.

Comment: why are you using locals()?

Comment: Thanks for your response, @matszwecja. I have many variables that need to be transformed in the same way, so I don't want to do the same transformation by rewriting the code incorporating the different variables i.e 
econ_data['choice_open_1_f'] = econ_data['choice_open_1_f'].astype(str).str.replace('/',' ')

econ_data['choice_open_1_m'] = econ_data['choice_open_1_m'].astype(str).str.replace('/',' ')

Comment: Thanks for your response, @deponovo. I do not have the 'choice_open_1_f_stop' column in my data frame as I believe that I am creating it in this line:locals()[econ_data[f"{z}_stop"]] = econ_data[f"{z}"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in x.split() if x not in stop_words))

Comment: @Michelle13 And why do you need `locals()` for that? Have you tried simple `econ_data[f"{z}_stop"] = `?

Comment: @matszwecja, thanks so much! That worked! I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: @Michelle13 repeated the same as an answer in case you want to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because you are trying to get value of `locals()[econ_data[f"{z}_stop"]]` which is not defined.
You should do a simple assignment `econ_data[f"{z}_stop"] =`  which dataframe handles and creates a key that does not exist if try to assign to it.